# Using skimr to create a data frame of summary statistics

Tags: r, summary, skimr

I have recently come across the package called `skimr` which helps create useful summary statistics. I have written the following codes to extract summary stats only on numerical columns. My first question is, is there a more direct way that skimr permits to specify the type of variables for which I want summary stats? My second question is, what does `append == TRUE`  actually achieve when I write the `my_skim` "closure"?

```
library(skimr)
library(dplyr)

### Creating an example dataset 

test.df1 <- data.frame("Year" = sample(2018:2020, 20, replace = TRUE), 
                       "Firm" = head(LETTERS, 5), 
                       "Exporter"= sample(c("Yes", "No"), 20, replace = TRUE), 
                       "Revenue" = sample(100:200, 20, replace = TRUE),
                         stringsAsFactors =  FALSE)

test.df1 <- rbind(test.df1, 
                    data.frame("Year" = c(2018, 2018),
                               "Firm" = c("Y", "Z"),
                               "Exporter" = c("Yes", "No"),
                               "Revenue" = c(NA, NA)))

test.df1 <- test.df1 %>% mutate(Profit = Revenue - sample(20:30, 22, replace = TRUE ))

### Using skimr package to extract summary stats

my_skim <- skim_with(numeric = sfl(minimum = min, maximum = max, hist = NULL), append = TRUE)

test.df1_skim1 <- test.df1 %>% 
 group_by(Year) %>% 
  my_skim() %>% 
   filter (skim_type != "character") %>% 
    select(-starts_with("character"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want summary of the numeric variables you could set all the other types to NULL or else you could run the skim and use `yank()` to get subtable for a type.
From   https://docs.ropensci.org/skimr/articles/skimr.html#reshaping-the-results-from-skim-

```
  skim(Orange) %>% yank("numeric")
```

The append option lets you either replace the default statistics or append to the defaults.